# Can't connect Barrier from Ubuntu 22.04 to Windows 10

Tags: networking, server

I have installed Barrier(v. 2.4) for both Ubuntu and Windows. Keeping the Ubuntu PC as server and the Windows as client (or vice-versa), I've been unable to establish a connection. Server Logs (Ubuntu machine are as follows):

```
[2022-05-23T19:41:16] INFO: starting server
[2022-05-23T19:41:16] INFO: config file: /tmp/Barrier.iSqQUR
[2022-05-23T19:41:16] INFO: log level: INFO
started server (IPv4/IPv6), waiting for clients
```

Whereas on the client side(Windows 10), following logs are there:

```
WARNING: failed to connect to server: Timed out
```

I've also tried to disabled the firewall as well as disabled the SSL from Barrier but nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

1. Open Terminal
2. Copy and past:

sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

3. Find #WaylandEnable=false and delete #
4. Ctrl + O to save and Enter to confirm
5. Reboot Ubuntu
6. Check with:

echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE -> x11

Windows 10

1. Open Windows Security.
2. Click on Firewall & network protection.
3. Click the Allow an app through firewall option. ...
4. Click the Change settings button.
5. Click Allow another app button
6. Locate the \Barrier\barriers.exe
7. Click the OK button

Done.

Comment: I did exactly that, but on the Windows machine it still is showing Timed Out. On the linux machine,  echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE -> x11
return nothing. 
Tried after restarting both the PCs and checked after both disabling and enabling SSLs
And did it for barriers.exe instead of barrier.exe as you mentioned. What is the difference?

Comment: @Faizan I think `x11` is the expected output of the command `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`, not part of it :) btw, I have the very same problem here and the proposed solution does not work. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check the followings:

- **Barrier version** of both Ubuntu and Windows should match to avoid incompatibilities. Just click `Help -> About Barrier...` and read the last lines. In the past I've experienced issues using different versions; currently I use `barrier 2.4.0`.
- **Client hostname** should match the corresponding entry in Server settings. It is used to check the client identity. From your server, click `Configure Server...` button and verify the name under the screen icons match all computer hostnames.
- By default, SSL encription is enabled. **Disable SSL certificate** if you get this error or similar:

```
ERROR: ssl certificate doesn't exist: <path_to_pem_file>
ERROR: could not load client certificates
ERROR: ssl error occurred (system call failure)
ERROR: failed to connect secure socket
```